# Почему есть учительница, но нет педагогини?

Tags: словообразование

Педагог и учитель - это, конечно, не синонимы, но слова, близкие по значению.
Но я заметила интересную закономерность: почему от слова "учитель" женский род образован давно и прочно - учительница, а вот от слова "педагог" - нет. Есть, конечно, разговорное "педагогиня", но это так, из области лингвистической шутки, скорее.
Также нет женского рода от многих других профессий. Почему так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположу, что "учить" является словом русского происхождения, а "педагогия" нет. В этой связи в языке устоялась трансформация родных слов, к иностранным словам неприменимая.

Answer (score 1):

Педагог - это скорее не профессия, а сфера научных интересов, призвание. Для званий (призваний) женского рода как правило не употребляется, ср. *русист, языковед, кандидат наук Иванова, но кандидатка на должность*.

Answer (score 1):

В русском языке существует ряд суффиксов со значением лица женского пола, но **они различаются по значению, стилю и области применения.**

Самыми продуктивными являются суффиксы К и НИЦ,  слова с этими суффиксами стилистически нейтральны: солистка,  аспирантка, летчица, учительница.

Суффиксы Ш и ИХ  имеют сниженную характеристику и допустимы только в разговорной речи: кассирша,  бухгалтерша, но: маникюрша, партнерша (нейтр.). Раньше они использовались для образования названий женщин по профессии мужа: мельничиха, генеральша.

Суффикс ИНЬ используется в небольшом количестве слов со значением  общественного статуса (барыня, боярыня, богиня, героиня, монахиня, рабыня) или жены титулованного лица (княгиня, герцогиня, графиня).

При образовании существительных с этими суффиксами учитывается фонетическая характеристика основы, так как нужный суффикс может не подходить к основе исходного слова.